# Xpath query with scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I want to extract in the following link http://gepris.dfg.de/gepris/projekt/268853 the String **Professor Dr. Michael Eiermann** from the category **beteiliger Wissenschaftler**. How must the Xpath query must be correct. From the output I get the String **Fachliche Zuordnung**

Code Snippet with Xpath query:

```
start_urls =['http://gepris.dfg.de/gepris/projekt/268853',]
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'content_frame')]/*[@id='projektbeschreibung']"):        
        lianjia = lianjiaItem()
        lianjia['Projekttitel'] = sel.xpath("//div/div/span/text()").extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

This xpath

```
response.xpath("//span[contains(., 'beteiligter Wissenschaftler')]/following-sibling::span[@class='value']/a/text()").extract()
```

returns array of Professors. The first one is `Professor Dr. Michael Eiermann`

Comment: @DaniiilMashkin the sel.xpath statement (Projekttitel), stays the same?

Comment: no, the xpath return array of strings, you don't need to use another xpath.